# How can I use a string variable as a path url in C++

Tags: c++, variables, file-io

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
main(){
char username[UNLEN+1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
GetUserName(username, &username_len);
string cmd("C:\\Users\\");
cmd+=username;
cmd+=("\\AppData\\Roaming\\MiniApps");
}
```

Now I have complete path url in "cmd", and i want to use this variable as a path in c++ file handling . like

```
ofstream file;
file.open(cmd,ios::out|ios::app);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem ? Or the question ?

Comment: file.open(cmd.cstr(), ios::app)

Comment: Compiler compiles with .c_str() ,but it dose not go to the path just create a file where .exe file is saved

Comment: @king4aol 'just create a file where .exe file is saved ' is not the unix/linux way

Comment: Would you please do a `cout << cmd;` and post the output?

Comment: You should try and avoid using a hard-coded path to the user's folder. There are many ways of doing this (environment variables, windows functions, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a file stream using ofstream, write the content and close.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    char username[UNLEN+1];
    DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
    GetUserName(username, &username_len);
    std::string cmd("C:\\Users\\");
    cmd+=username;
    cmd+=("\\AppData\\Roaming\\MiniApps.txt");
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open (cmd.c_str(), std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    file << " Hello World";
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With C++11 you can do

```
ofstream file(cmd,ios::app);
```

Without you have to do

```
ofstream file(cmd.c_str(),ios::app);
```

Comment: Compiler compiles with .c_str() ,but it dose not go to the path just create a file where .exe file is saved –